# OpenCL array returning 0

Tags: opencl, gpu

I'm relatively new to OpenCL and having a problem accessing an array. I am using printf to debug the program.

The (admittedly contrived) code is as follows:

```
__constant static int array_2[4] = {
    0, 1,
    2, 3
};

void __kernel first_kernel(__global const int* input, __global int* output) {
    __private int array_0[2];
    __private int array_1[] {
        100, 101, 102, 103
    };
    for (int index < 0; index < 2; index++) {
        array_0[0] = array_1[array_2[2 * index]];
        array_0[1] = array_1[array_2[2 * index + 1]];
        printf("array_0: [%d, %d]\n", array_0[0], array_0[1]);
        printf("array_1[0] = %d\n", array_1[0]);
        printf("array_2[2 * index] = %d\n", array_2[2 * index]);
        printf("array_1[array_2[2 * index]] = %d\n", array_1[array_2[2 * index]]);
    }
}
```

The output for the first iteration is:
    array_0: [0, 0]
    array_1[0] = 100
    array_2[2 * index] = 0
    array_1[array_2[2 * index]] = 0

Why is the output of the last line "0"? It seems that accessing the array using a constant 0 gives the correct result, but accessing the same array using "array_2[2 * index], which is equal to 0, gives an incorrect result. What's going on?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For context: "array 2" here is meant to be a lookup table for values. "array 1" is an array which will differ per work item based on the input and work item position. "array 0" is an intermediary array used to determine the output, changed each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: The line `for (int index < 0; index < 2; index++) {` contains a syntax error. Are you sure you're *actually* running this code and the code you posted genuinely suffers from this issue, or are you vaguely translating from some other code which is misbehaving due to some other bug that is unrelated to the code you posted? (`__private int array_1[] { 100, 101, 102, 103  };` also contains a syntax error, so I'm wondering if you've not actually isolated your issue because you haven't tested your minimal sample.)

Comment: My guess is you've got undefined behaviour elsewhere in your code affecting this code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @pmdj. I will try to find a way to post my actual code, which may not be possible due to academic constraints!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with reducing your code down to fit a Stack Overflow question, in fact that's generally recommended. However, in this case I think you've edited out the bug. I suspect you might discover where the bug is if you reduce your code step by step and keep testing at each step. You might find that removing seemingly unrelated code suddenly makes the bug disappear. At least that will help you pinpoint the code that really is causing the problem.